# Searching for (freeware) database migration tool

Tags: sql, database, migration, dump

I'm searching for a tool to dump a database including DDL and content as plain SQL-Sсript, so that it can be archived in a plain text format. I know e.g. the Oracle dump tools or MySQL dump, but is there a tool which can connect to different data sources and get the job done? GUI would be great.

Comment: By different data sources do you mean different database implementations (Oracle, SQL Server, etc.)? Or do you mean two different connections to the same kind of database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/. Gui, cross-platform and supports any database with jdbc driver.

Comment: Include an automatic DBCopy plugin too... might let a user omit the need for SQL Script entirely!

Answer (score 2):

Look at set of SSMA Microsft's free tools (Oracle, Sybase, MySQL..) 
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Migration-oracle.aspx